# Ноутбук не видит драйверы МФУ, что делать?

Tags: драйвер, windows-8, принтер

купили вчера б/у МФУ Xerox Phaser 6121MFP, в нем сканер, принтер, ксерокс, факс, короче, вся фигня, но он старый, у нас дома есть ноутбук на windows 8.1 и windows 11, я нашла на официальном сайте драйверы, совместимые с windows 8.1, попробовала поставить их на оба ноутбука, после установки начинает искать принтер и не находит, хотя принтер подключен и драйверы, вроде как, установлены. Проблема одна и та же на обоих ноутах. Продавец проверял - все печатало и работало исправно. Сканировать и печатать может, а с ноутбука изображение не печатает - во время печати принтер не отображается, а при попытке поиска пишет "Никаких принтеров не найдено". Что делать?

Comment: напишите в техподдержку. если оттуда не ответят, или ответят, что такую модель уже не поддерживают, то несите принтер куда не жалко: на помойку или куда-нибудь типа avito.

Answer (score -1):

Если при подключении принтер даже не опознается как неопознанное устройство - проблема может быть в разъеме, кабеле. Если опознается - то искать другие драйвера.

Comment: Опознается, пишет "Готово к использованию", именно в драйверах беда

Comment: А драйверы другие искала, все сайты остальные, кроме официального, фишинговые, скачивается какая-то рекламная хрень

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нет, не стоило, но спасибо за комментарий.